# Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces error (in CSVHelper method) when running the application installed by Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, setup-project, csvhelper, base-class-library

I have a WPF application that reads a CSV file using `CSVHelper` which I installed using `NuGet`. Here's the project, system, etc version info.

> Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Version  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build
>   7601
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.5
>
> NuGet Package Manager   5.4.0
>
> WPF Project Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2
>
> CSVHelper Version: 15.0.5

CSV reader method is straightforward; read a file and put it in a list. Nothing fancy. I'll link the entire project at the bottom so you can download and try it out if you want.

When I run the executable made in either `Release` or `Debug` builds, they work fine. They read the file, put contents in a list, and display on a `DataGrid` just fine. As a next step, I created a standard `Visual Studio Setup` project, and created an `msi` installer, which I used to install the app in my PC.

When I run that executable (which is in my Program Files directory), however, the application throws an exception. Here's the exception message and Stack Trace.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
   at ReadCSVTest.MainWindow.ReadPeopleList(String path, List`1& people, String& msg)
   at ReadCSVTest.MainWindow..ctor()
```

Since the error says couldn't load the assembly `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`, I added that from NuGet and ran everything again, and I still get the error. What's the problem here? What does it mean that `Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.`? And why do I only get this exception when I run the executable installed by the Setup project?

Please download the entire project from [HERE](https://github.com/sachintha81/PublicDownloads/blob/master/ReadCSVTest.zip).

Comment: I wonder if it might be related to this issue. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1462  You might try downgrading to CsvHelper version 14 or 13 and see if it works.

Comment: I have the same issue. I had to downgrade to CsvHelper 12.3.2 abd Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces to 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me try that out and see how it goes!

Comment: @Jones, downgrading to those exact version numbers fixed it for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so anyone runs into the same issue in the future; as Jones suggested in the comments, downgrading each of the two libraries to following versions fixed the issue for me.

```
CsvHelper ==> 12.3.2
```

And

```
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces ==> 1.0.0
```